# How to handle the modules which are under the same menu by using single xpath expression for all the modules

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

[this is the example from our application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qj1cO.png)

I am trying this code but not working

```
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Menu for Distribution']"));
        Actions act=new Actions(driver);
        act.moveToElement(ele).perform();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        for (int i=3; i<=10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
            ele1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@target='frame_main'])[i]"));
            ele1.click();
        }
```

Comment: can you share a link to that page and all your relevant code?

Comment: Can you explain more about what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following method to click submenu option,

> by calling **clickSubMenu("New Consignee");**

```
public void clickSubMenu(String optionName){
    By mainMenu = By.xpath("//a[@title='Menu for Distribution']");
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(mainMenu));
    action.build().perform();
    
    By subMenu = By.xpath("//a[text()='"+optionName+"']");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(subMenu));
    driver.findElement(subMenu).click();
}
```

**Steps :**

1. Hover over to the main menu
2. wait for the visiblity
3. Click the submenu